# C# service timer not firing on windows server 2008 r2

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, service

I have a c# service that has a timer which should fire after 24 hours. The service works fine on my development machine (windows 7 Professional) and when deployed onto a windows server 2003 environment. When I deploy the service to a windows server 2008 r2 environment, the service can be started but the timer does not fire as expected. Is there anything setting that I need to enable so that the timer can fire in windows server 2008 r2?

thanx

Comment: Could it be that the timer is firing but the code behind it is not working because of some permissions issue? Is the service running under the Network Service account? If so, make it run under an admin account and see if anything changes.